# Truffle & Web3 1.0.0-beta : does it work for anyone?

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-contract

I'm trying to make the latest Truffle (3.4.3) and Web3 (1.0.0-beta11) to work together in a React app.

It fails when I try to call `myContractInstance.deployed()`

```
import { default as Eth} from 'web3-eth';
import { default as Contract } from 'truffle-contract';
import myContract_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/myContract.json';
...
var eth = new Eth(Eth.givenProvider || "http://localhost:8545");
var myContractDef = Contract(myContract_artifacts);
myContractDef.setProvider( eth.currentProvider);
var myContractInstance = await myContractDef.deployed();
```

the last line  throws an error with localhost http provider (testrpc v4.0.1):

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at Provider.sendAsync (bundle.js:113598)
at RequestManager.sendAsync (bundle.js:121952)
at Object.get [as getNetwork] (bundle.js:23150)
at bundle.js:114052
at Promise (<anonymous>)
at Function.detectNetwork (bundle.js:114043)
at Function.deployed (bundle.js:113991)
at App.componentDidMount (bundle.js:60259)
at bundle.js:68136
at measureLifeCyclePerf (bundle.js:67947)
at bundle.js:68135
at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (bundle.js:39530)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (bundle.js:70093)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (bundle.js:26044)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (bundle.js:25991)
at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (bundle.js:41397)
at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (bundle.js:25978)
at Object.batchedUpdates (bundle.js:69759)
at Object.batchedUpdates (bundle.js:13827)
at Object._renderNewRootComponent (bundle.js:41590)
at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (bundle.js:41672)
at render (bundle.js:41693)
```

but also with Metamask (v3.9.0):

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: MetamaskInpageProvider - sendAsync not overwritten
    at MetamaskInpageProvider.sendAsync (inpage.js:219)
    at Provider.sendAsync (bundle.js:113598)
    at RequestManager.sendAsync (bundle.js:121952)
    at Object.get [as getNetwork] (bundle.js:23150)
    at bundle.js:114052
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Function.detectNetwork (bundle.js:114043)
    at Function.deployed (bundle.js:113991)
    at App.componentDidMount (bundle.js:60259)
    at bundle.js:68136
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (bundle.js:67947)
    at bundle.js:68135
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (bundle.js:39530)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (bundle.js:70093)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (bundle.js:26044)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (bundle.js:25991)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (bundle.js:41397)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (bundle.js:25978)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (bundle.js:69759)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (bundle.js:13827)
    at Object._renderNewRootComponent (bundle.js:41590)
    at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (bundle.js:41672)
```

I've got the same errors when I try:

```
myContractDef.deployed().then( function( error, result)  { ... } )
```

Comment: I have the same problem.It seems in web3js 1.0 there is a lot of changes from the stable version. Did you find any solution?

Comment: no solution yet and i coudn't find any info on truffle github when do they plan to make it work with web3 1.0..

Comment: Do you have an example repo that others could try?

Comment: Happening to me right now... just did 'npm install --save' of the default stuff...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to make it work with recently released `truffle-contract`.

- web3@1.0.0-beta.20
- truffle-contract@3.0.0
- truffle@3.4.9

Issues for me so far:

- doesn't work with http provider: ["TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/issues/57) UPDATE: there is a workaround for this issue, check the comments on the issue linked
- Page refresh in browser makes web3 functions to halt. Still investigating if it's an error in my code UPDATE: chrome update to Version 61.0.3163.91 solved this issue

A bit of work needed for migration, these what I've found so far:

- util functions moved to `web3.utils`. Eg. `fromWei`, `toWei`, `sha3` etc.
- `getBalance` returns string now and not a BN
- `fromWei`/`toWei` now returns string when `bignumber.js` bignumber passed ([see issue](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1042)  )
- `web3.eth.filter` removed, there is `web3.eth.subscribe` instead, bit of refactor required
- accounts returned by `web3.eth.getAccounts` etc.  are with checksum now (ie. upper/lower case used). [See docs](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#note-on-checksum-addresses)

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the truffle folks to answer on gitter, but [here's the version of web3](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/master/package.json#L25) that they are using in the truffle suite, which is known to work (I'm using it right now):  (from their `package.json`: `"web3": "^0.20.1",`

I changed to this version of web3 and deploying appears to work correctly.

Now I'm getting an `invalid address` when I use the contract but that's probably a different problem.  (oddly enough contract.address is valid...)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem with web3 not working and throwing the same error.

The reason is I was using the supposedly stable version web3@0.20.6, but there seem to be backwards compatibility issues now.

I just installed the latest web3 version (web3@1.0.0-beta.34) using

```
npm install web3@latest --save
```

and now it works again.